# POST firebase auth 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I should make user auth with React JS and Firebase. I have written the codes bellow and getting
`POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=XXXXXXX%3B 400`  I have done everything following the instruction but don't know what the problem is. When the user signs up, it is not appearing in firebase identifier.

**base.js**

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  ...
});

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export default app;
```

**AuthContext.js**

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth } from "../base";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "@firebase/auth";
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  function signup(email, password) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    signup,
  };
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**Code in signUp page**

```
const { signup, currentUser } = useAuth();

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const v1 = USER_REGEX.test(user);
    const v2 = PWD_REGEX.test(pwd);
    if (!v1 || !v2) {
      setErrMsg("Invalid Entry");
      return;
    }

    try {
      setErrMsg('')
      setLoading(true)
      await signup(emailRef.current.value, pwdRef.current.value);
    } catch {
      setErrMsg("Failed to create an account");
    }
    setLoading(false)
    console.log(user, emailRef, pwdRef);
    setSuccess(true);
  };
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).catch((e) => console.log(e))`? that might show some more details.

Comment: @Dharmaraj  thanks, now I know what was the problem. I have deleted firebase project, built again and configured.